# Checkboxes read-only attribute HTML

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am developing a website, and I need a certain checkbox that when is unchecked the correspondent input box has the read-only attribute and when I check it the read-only attribute gets removed from the input box. Right now, what happens is I load the website, the checkbox is unchecked and the input box does not has the read-only attribute as it was supposed to. Altough when I check and uncheck it the input box gets the read-only attribute.
Why is this happening?

Here is the Javascript code:

```
  const checkbox = document.getElementById("check_pt");
  const inputElement = document.getElementById("pi_pt");

  checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (!(checkbox.checked)) {
      inputElement.setAttribute("readonly", "true");
    } else {
      inputElement.removeAttribute("readonly"); 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Document is parsed based on the source code you send from your server. Any change to a live document doesn't have an effect to your server-side code, unless you're specifically saving the new state.

Comment: Your code is not executed on page load, only when checkbox changes _after_ user has clicked it

Answer (score 1):

Your function sets the `readonly` attribute **when the checkbox is changed**.

It doesn't get set when the document initially loads, because the user hasn't changed it.

If you want the function to run when the document initially loads, then you'll need to call it at that time. Alternatively, you could set the attribute in the HTML instead of modifying it with JS (which generally makes more sense when setting default values for attributes). Note that if you do either of these, then the state can never change so the change event handler will never run.)